# How to process a .proto file using protobuf-net

Tags: c#, ruby, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have started using the protobuf-net lib to communication between some of the programs I'm maintaining. I have also been able to decode messages from C# to Ruby. My ruby ProtoBuf lib is using a .proto file to generate the ruby code. In the interest of having to make changes in as few places as possible I would like to have protobuf-net use the same .proto file. Looking though the protobuf-net folders there is a Dll named ProtoBufGenerator and the protobuf exe but I cant find any instructions on if I can make protobuf-net work this way.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out Marc Gravell's blog, [this post](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/07/protobuf-net-now-with-added-orcas.html) specifically.
You basically set it as a custom build tool for the file in Visual Studio.

Comment: Wow, all I had to do was add the file to the project since i already had installed protobuf-net. Very cool.

Comment: @JustSmith (and @Thorarin) - just for completeness, there is also a command-line tool, `protogen.exe`.